# "Thread was being aborted." in aspx SOAP Service

Tags: iis-7

I have a aspx soap service that accesses an enterprise database via Tuxedo. The soap service is running on IIS7/Windows 2008 R2.  We occasionally get "Thread was being aborted." and the SOAP call fails to return. Due to network/db performance/sketchy backend issues it entirely possible the calls are long running (up to 20 min) We can afford to be patient. We think IIS is killing the thread for running to long. Scalability is not an issue at this time, since we see a max of 10 concurrent requests. Is there a way to configure IIS to give more time before killing the thread ?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility may be the executionTimeout setting in web.config. The default is 110 secs. If the debug=true switch is set in web.config, then this value is ignored and timeout never occurs. Increasing this value will allow IIS to give more time before killing hte thread.

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="110"/>
</system.web>
```